# How to access the mp3 stored in iPhone in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

How does one access an MP3 stored in iPhone iTune_controls directory?  When i want to see the MP3 it is not visible for me in my applcation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but it sounds like you want to access an MP3 from your app that is in the iTunes (iPod?) area of the phone, is this correct?

If so then you can't directly access the file, since your app runs in an isolated sand-box.

If on the other hand you're wanting to play an MP3 that's part of your app then look in the [iPhone Library - Audio Queue Services](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) section.